# Write Text in PDF in Hindi font using pdfbox

Tags: java

I want to write text in hindi font in pdf using pdf box. Can anyone help.

I am trying to write code like this.

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();    
PDPage page = new PDPage();   
doc.addPage(page);   
PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF( doc, new File("c:\\shusha.ttf"));   
font.setFontEncoding(new WinAnsiEncoding());   
PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream( doc, page, true, false );   
content.setFont(font, 15);   
content.beginText();

content.moveTextPositionByAmount( 200, 100 );   
content.drawString( "Aamarsa" );   
content.endText();   
content.close();   
doc.save( new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\testOutput.pdf")));   
doc.close();
```

Later I also tried to add encoding, but is not useful. I could not find any encoding class which supports UTF-8 in PDFBox.

Comment: Ok , good , carry on , ask when you have done some research and posted your question which shows some effort !

Comment: God helps those who help themselves. Most of us here on SO believes in it. Try to help yourself by writing code and sharing where you are stuck, Good luck!

Comment: Amit, SO is not meant for asking tutorials on things. If you have done some work and have specific questions, ask them here

Comment: You should start with writing "some" characters in pdf using pdf box.

Comment: I am sorry guys i just posted it, i thought if any one has already done it. Editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here i tried this, and got something what you want, use the same code,

simply download the PDTrueTypeFont.java (from pdfbox-1.8.2-src.jar) file and include into your project, then modify the condition

before,

```
int platformEncoding = cmaps[i].getPlatformEncodingId();
                    if ( CMAPTable.ENCODING_UNICODE == platformEncoding)
```

modified,

```
int platformEncoding = cmaps[i].getPlatformEncodingId();
                    if ( CMAPTable.ENCODING_UNICODE == platformEncoding ||
                         CMAPTable.ENCODING_SYMBOL == platformEncoding)
```

because, this class not supporting the ENCODING_SYMBOL. so only you are not able to create the pdf with different fonts.

Don't include the PDTrueTypeFont from the package pdfbox. Use from your local package.